# Stop href event bubbling

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a td tag from javascript. It has an addEventListener/attachEvent set for clicks. Inside this tag I have an inner with 'a' tag. I need to run the href without triggering the td click.
Until now i have it working in IE:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<a href='"+url+"' onclick='event.cancelBubble = true; 
if(event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); }'>"
```

Comment: are you sure this is possible? iirc, different browsers propagate the event in different directions, so in some browsers the `td` event will fire before the `a` event and in some browsers after.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the href"? Do you mean if the user clicks on the `<a>` tag you want it to do its thing without triggering the click event on the `<td>`? What happens with the code you have so far?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly!:) Until now i can get this sort of behavior in IE.

Comment: Why not to do it using jquery or other client framework that support different browser support?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it  working in chrome by setting the catch event to bubble (the 'false' statement)

```
cell.addEventListener("click", function(){          
        ...},false);
```